Convert Pandas Df.info() Into a SQL DDL
I am trying to take a pandas df and move it to a new Vertica table. Is there a way to convert the df.info() so that i coincides as an automated process for building the SQL insert?
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
cw_provs.info(buf=buffer)
lines = buffer.getvalue().splitlines()
df = (pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in lines[5:-2]], columns=lines[3].split())
       .drop('Count',axis=1)
       #.drop('Non-Null Count',axis=0)
       #.rename(columns={'Non-Null':'Non-Null Count'})
     )
df.drop(df.columns[[0,2]],axis=1,inplace=True)
df['Dtype'] = df['Dtype'].map({'object': 'VARCHAR', 'Int64': 'INT'})
print (df)

TO VERTICA
dataframe_list=df.values.tolist()
with vertica_python.connect(**conn_info) as connection:
    cur = connection.cursor()
    # drop table 
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cw_provs") 
    # Create table 
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE cw_provs 
                ( a INT
                 ,b VARCHAR
                )"""
                ,use_prepared_statements=True)
    # insert statement 
    sql = "INSERT INTO df_from_python VALUES (?, ?)"
    for index,elem in enumerate(dataframe_list): #iterating the list using index(int)
        cur.execute(sql,dataframe_list[index],use_prepared_statements=True) #here cursor is using the existing cursor objec
        
    cur.execute("COMMIT") #committing the changes to the table
connection.close()

How can i automate this section where this comes from the df.info() conversion :
( a INT
  ,b VARCHAR )

